# How do I disply a list of all Super Users who have not been active here for more than a certain length of time?

Tags: discussion

I had seen a clever solution to an excel problem online which brought me to Stack Exchange's "Super Users" service. But I have forgotten the user's name as well as the excel problem that I had researched on the internet, so I cannot find that user anymore. The only information I have is that the user had not been active in Super User for a couple of years, plus I remember the profile picture. Is there a list of users I can bring up in here who have not been active since 2021, so at least I could narrow my visual search?

Comment: It does - and OP , you really need to ask your meta questions on meta, and not the main site and getting it moved over

Comment: According to the SE site list [page](https://stackexchange.com/sites), there are 1.5M users on Superuser. Many have not been active for years so expect to go through well over 1M profiles.

Comment: @doneal24 That's why I need your help. The Super User's alias ended with "a9" I don't remember what letters preceded the a9, but was one word, like a name and a 9 at the end. The avatar was a black face with two very shiny yellow/red eyes, like inside the head was a furnace. That's all I have, except that he/she had found an excellent solution for a problem that I had struggled with and was researching it on the internet. So much excel has since come and gone through my mind that leaves no idea what that particular problem was :-) If I knew which one it was it would be easy to find its author.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to be a Problem X Y. You want to find a questions, but instead of asking for help to find the question you are asking to find a user. I think that that you should focus on searching based on the content rather than the user's avatar as it has been a couple of years inactive and could have changed at any time.

Anyway...

[Superuser](https://superuser.com) hasn't a list of users based on their last active date. The page of users is the following: [Users - Superuser](https://superuser.com/users). It has tabs to view users by Reputation, New Users, Votes, Edits, and Moderators. At the bottom of the page, you can find the links to the Reputation Leagues page.

On [StackExchange](https://data.stackexchange.com) you can find the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. From it you can create a query to list users based on their last active date among many other many things. It has help page. Also, you can learn about it in Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks @Ruben. I'll see what I can do with the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. My goal is not to find the problem that user had solved! I already mastered whatever it was back then. I want to see that user's other contributions and study some or all of them. And as you see with this example, the criteria at my disposal in the search tool being "Reputation, New Users, Votes, Edits, and Moderators" none is worth a dime in finding the user. This place is not set right. Why not offering the use of wild cards * and ? in the queries? A little bit of sense goes a long way here.

Comment: @Physfit wildcards are supported on the data explorer. How about `select * from Users where DisplayName like ‘%a9’`?

Comment: You are welcome :)  Criticism / [meta-tag:feature-request] / asking for help about the general features is better to be done in [meta.se]. If you recall more details about  `^.+a9$` user (a quick attempt to write a regex expression, not intention to discuss regex here) I suggest you to post a new question here as questions should not change too much once they got an answer and should not use comments to have extended discussions. You might also take a look to the [chat] to see if some of the regulars could help you to find this user.

Comment: Scroll all the way down to the bottom of page. In the page footer, look at the bottom of "STACK EXCHANGE NETWORK", click on Data.

Comment: Comments are not intended for extended discussions.

Comment: @Physfit "His contribution is at:  [Indirect Function in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/1578963). But there is _no_way_ to get to his name and his contributions starting from the Super User site. " So go to that link and **click on his username**. That takes you to his profile and all of his contributions.

Comment: @Physfit https://superuser.com/users/1210616/rounit